# MobileFirst Platform CLI unable to build xcode 7.2 project with JSON Store

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I have a cordova project that contains mfp JSON Store. When I build the project with xcode 7.2 (enable Bitcode is set to false), it will run into an error:

```
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup", referenced from:
  +[JSONStoreSecurityUtils _doEncrypt:key:withIV:] in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreSecurityUtils.o)


  +[JSONStoreSecurityUtils _doDecrypt:key:withIV:withCorrectIVConversion:withCorrectKeyConversion:] in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreSecurityUtils.o)
[...50 further errors...]
"_sqlite3_step", referenced from:


  ___36-[JSONStoreDatabaseManager execute:]_block_invoke in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreDatabaseManager.o)


  ___35-[JSONStoreDatabaseManager update:]_block_invoke in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreDatabaseManager.o)


  ___47-[JSONStoreDatabaseManager deleteFromDatabase:]_block_invoke in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreDatabaseManager.o)


  ___47-[JSONStoreDatabaseManager selectInto:withSQL:]_block_invoke in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreDatabaseManager.o)


  ___50-[JSONStoreDatabaseManager selectAllInto:withSQL:]_block_invoke in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreDatabaseManager.o)


  ___35-[JSONStoreDatabaseManager insert:]_block_invoke in IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore(JSONStoreDatabaseManager.o)


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64





clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looks like it doesn't have the relevant JSONStore libraries for architecture arm64. If I try to run on a simulator, it fails with not found for architecture x86_64.

If you want to reproduce the issue, follow these steps:

- I used this [project](https://github.com/andriivasylchenko/hybridWallet/archive/lab2.48.zip) from mfp.help
- Added the ios environment: mfp cordova platform add
- mfp push
- Open the project in xcode, disable bitcode and run on device/simulator

mfp cordova plugin list shows the following:

```
cordova-plugin-mfp 7.1.0 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore 7.1.0 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - JSONStore"
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 7.1.0 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.13 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.11 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.11 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.globalization 0.3.3 "Globalization"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.4 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.14 "Network Information"
```

I tried to update the plugins via mfp cordova plugin update, but that didn't help.

I use this version of cli:
$ mfp -v
7.1.0.00.20151023-1449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find an instruction how to fix the issue here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iiesbpgrd7bj0c8/iOSfix.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Using the same CLI version and creating a new Cordova application, adding the iOS platform and the JSONStore plug-in, the build process in Xcode 7.2 passes successfully. This may be a specific issue with the provided sample.

Since you are an IBMer as well, I suggest contacting Andrii Vasylchenko directly via Notes as he maintains this sample and could update it.

Comment: I did the same on my machine and it also worked. So, I guess you are right. I will check with Andrii to fix the sample.